# Always use same animation for Nimbus JProgressBar when running in indeterminate mode

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, jprogressbar

I would like to force Nimbus to ALWAYS use the rolling blocks rather than oscillating circles in JProgressBar ... Images found in another question:

[Nimbus - Different JProgressBar Styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20750708/nimbus-different-jprogressbar-styles)

Is this doable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Netbeans' indeterminate progress-bar style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24409879/how-to-use-netbeans-indeterminate-progress-bar-style)